# Can't see Preview of Image to Upload when using ngRepeat and ng-src

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-ng-repeat, filereader

I've created a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/poakey1/pen/EPqreR) of my problem.

I'm using the HTML5 `FileReader` and Angular to create a simple multi-file upload with a preview of the images that are to be uploaded.

**The problem:**
I am not getting the selected images in the `ng-repeat` span.  I do however get the correct image data when I log it out to the console... what am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="my.app" ng-controller="FileUploadController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h3>File Upload Test</h3>
    </div>
    <input type="file" class="well" id="files" name="files[]" multiple onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload()" />
    <span ng-repeat="x in images">
      <img ng-src="{{x}}" />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("my.app", []);

app.controller("FileUploadController", function($scope) {
  $scope.images = [];

  $scope.upload = function() {
    var files = document.getElementById("files").files;

    if (files) {
      for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
            console.log(e.target.result);
            $scope.images.push(e.target.result);
          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }; 
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/orion514/kkhxsgLu/136/ has the same working implementation.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in images">
<img class="thumb" ng-src="{{x}}" />
```

```
$scope.images = [];

$scope.imageUpload = function(event){
     var files = event.target.files; //FileList object

     for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
         var file = files[i];
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded; 
             reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }

    $scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.images.push(e.target.result);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it better to wrap the code in `$scope.apply` or just call `$scope.apply()` afterwards?  Both work...

Answer (score 1):

try `$scope.$apply()` when you modify collection like below,

```
     reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
        $scope.images.push(e.target.result);
        $scope.$apply();
      }
```